# SharePoint 2013 Designer workflow Rest API: update items in multi valued lookup column

Tags: rest, sharepoint, lookup, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-workflow

I am trying to update the SharePoint online list items using Rest API in SharePoint Workflow 2013.I am able to update all the columns except Multi valued lookup column.
I am getting the below error :
An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected.

I have tried the below code :
Passing ID & Value
1;#abc;#2;#xyz

& i have tried passing dictionary also but no luck every time getting some or the other error.

Please let me know how to achieve this.